# How to give a price value the $ sign in SQL?

Tags: sql

Okay. So here's the problem I have been running into in my code. After about an hour of searching the web and trying to locate a solution, I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong with the code. I have the following query

```
SELECT TITLE, COST, RETAIL FROM BOOKS WHERE TITLE LIKE 'H%';
```

I need the value of "COST" to come out with a $ sign before the numbers. If the price were to come up as 26.68, I need it to come out as $26.68

Any ideas?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: That is something that you typically would do in your presentation layer not in SQL.  But if you need to do that then you will need to concatenate the $ to your value.

Comment: easy way is you dont put `$` in databse. you just concatenate it on user display

Comment: Not entirely sure what you mean, but if you are asking me what program I am using to write this, the answer would be Oracle.

Answer (score 2):

Use the to_char function as it is meant for this and provides other formatting options as well.

For instance this will provide the dollar sign and thousand place separators:

```
select title, to_char(cost, '$9,999,999,999,999.99') as cost, retail
  from books
 where title like 'H%';
```

SQL fiddle example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/27869/0

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/sql_elements004.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a concatenation of '$' + COST

In Oracle it's :

```
SELECT 
    TITLE
    , '$' || COST as COST
    , RETAIL 
FROM 
    BOOKS 
WHERE TITLE LIKE 'H%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT TITLE, CONCAT('$', COST) as cost, RETAIL FROM BOOKS WHERE TITLE LIKE 'H%';
```

Comment: Thank you so much! The textbook was unable to tell me anything on how to concatenate. It did work, thank you very much for your help.

Comment: if the answer helped, plz  make sure to mark it as answer. Good day